# Optimizing a program for calculating twin numbers between in a certain interval

Tags: c

```
int if_no_prime(int n)
{ 
    int prime, no_of_denominators=0; 
    for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if (n%i == 0)
            no_of_denominators++;
    }
    if (no_of_denominators == 2) 
        prime=1;  
    else
        prime=0;
    return prime;
}

int main()
{
    clock_t begin = clock();
    int beginning, end, i, prime1, prime2;

    printf("Enter the interval: ");
    scanf(" %d %d", &beginning, &end);
    for (i=beginning; i<=end; i++)
    {
                                //here
        prime1=if_no_prime(i);   
        if (prime1)
        {
            prime2=if_no_prime(i+2);
            if (prime1 && prime2)
                printf("The numbers %d and %d are twins\n", i, i+2);
        }
    }
    clock_t end=clock();
    double time_spent=(double)(end-begin);
    printf("Compile time: %f", (double)time_spent);
    return 0;
}
```

This code works, but I want to make it faster. When I plug in `i` directly to be tested, my compile time is 3010. Whatever that number means. But if I plug in `i` through an other variable on the line "here", my compile time is 2431.

Can someone explain to me why is it slower if I plug in the value directly, and how does timing work in c?

Comment: Please format your code properly and don't dump it. If you expect help from us, we expect some effort from you.

Comment: Just a comment while i review your code: you are mistaking compile and run times. Compiler is the time it takes to translate your C code to object code (its done before you run the program). And run time is the time it takes your program to execute (in this case it applies to the time it takes to perform the algorithm).

Comment: It can not compile as `end` is defined twice: "`error: conflicting types for ‘end’
         clock_t end=clock();`"

Comment: Regardless of the question itself (what do you mean by "plugging in a variable"?!) your code does not compile at all: `prog.c:32:9: error: redefinition of 'end' with a different type: 'clock_t' (aka 'long') vs 'int'`

Comment: Sorry for the badly formatted code, I don't know any better. Trying my best @hellow .

Comment: @Spyware please take a look at the edit Mike has done for your and try to format your code in the future exactly like that. One can now see where the code belongs to and easily find something bad. You should always always format your code, for your own safety ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i commented:

> you are mistaking compile and run times. Compiler is the time it takes
> to translate your C code to object code (its done before you run the
> program). And run time is the time it takes your program to execute
> (in this case it applies to the time it takes to perform the
> algorithm).

Also you were starting the clock before you asked the user for input, so the time you were measuring was: the time the user spent typing the characters + the time of the actual algorithm.

One last thing, dont use `clock()` for measuring times that require precission. I provided you with a common implementation that gives you the times in microseconds.

## How times work in C?

time.h's `clock()` function returns a struct `clock_t` that contains the current number of processor clocks that have ticked since you started the execution.

Divide it by the constant CLOCKS_PER_SEC (Usually 1000) and you will get the seconds elapsed.

## Now for the identation and other stuff

Here you have your code working and improved. Its much more legible and sightly faster.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

double microsecs() {
    struct timeval t;
    if (gettimeofday(&t, NULL) < 0 ) return 0.0;
    return (t.tv_usec + t.tv_sec * 1000000.0);
}

int if_no_prime(int n) { 
    int no_of_denominators=0; 

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        if (n%i==0) no_of_denominators++;
    
    return (no_of_denominators == 2);
}


int main() {

    int beginning, end, i, prime1, prime2;

    printf("Enter the interval: ");
    scanf(" %d %d", &beginning, &end);

    double begin=microsecs();

    for(i = beginning; i <= end; i++) {
                               //here
        prime1=if_no_prime(i);   

        if(prime1) {
            prime2 = if_no_prime(i+2);
            if(prime1 && prime2) printf("The numbers %d and %d are twins\n", i, i+2);
        }
    }

    printf("Execute time: %lf", microsecs()-begin);

    return 0;
}
```

P.D As i dont understand what "plugin in" a variable means i cannot answer that part. As long as you clarify me i will edit this answer.

Comment: What i meant by "plug in" was to assign a value to something. In this case it was to the function `if_no_prime()` . When I assigned `i` to another variable let's say `var` , and then I assign `var` to be executed in the function `if_no_prime(var)`, i would get a faster execution time then before.

Comment: @Spyware it was probably due to the fact that you were loosing a lot of precission using clock + counting in the users's input time. Try now with the code ive given you and let me know if that phenomenom reproduces.

Comment: `gettimeofday` is not in standard C but in Posix and also deprecated. The new function (sincePOSIX.1- 2001) is `clock_gettime`.   It's looks a bit like nitpicking, admitted, but not every OS supports Posix fully or in parts. You  might not even have an OS in the first place (e.g.: almost all of the IoTs).

Comment: @deamentiaemundi I didn't knew it. Its always good to learn something new. We use `gettimeofday` in our algorithms assignments in uni. If you want feel free to edit my answer! Have a nice day.